# Translator, only accepts one word, why not the rest

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I am trying to create a program that translates English to PigLatin. I have most of the components, but if I enter in more than one word, it only translates the first word. Where is the issue and how do I fix it.

```
public class PigLatin{
public static String translate(String phrase){
String [] returnArray=phrase.split(" ");
String [] translateArray=new String [returnArray.length];
for(int i=0;i<returnArray.length;i++){
  translateArray[i]=translateWord(returnArray[i]);
}

return StringLib.join(translateArray, " ");//translated Array
 }
public static String translateWord(String word) { 
String tword=word;
int indexVowel=indexOfFirstVowel(tword);
if(indexOfFirstVowel(tword)==0){
  tword=tword+"yay";
}
else {
  tword=tword.substring(indexOfFirstVowel(tword),tword.length())+tword.substring(0,indexOfFirstVowel(tword))+"ay";
} 
return tword;
}
public static int indexOfFirstVowel(String word) {//check where the first vowel is
String vowels = "aeiouy";
String loweredWord=word.toLowerCase();
for (int index=0;index<loweredWord.length();index++){
    if(vowels.contains(String.valueOf(loweredWord.charAt(index)))){
        return index;
        }
}
return -1;
}


public static void main(String [] args){
Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a phrase:");
String trans=translate(inp.next());
System.out.println("Here is your phrase in Pig Latin.");
System.out.println(trans);


 }
```

String.join translates the array into a String and here is that code

```
public class StringLib {

public static String join(String[] strs, String sep) {
    String joined = "";

    if (strs.length > 0) {
        joined = strs[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
            joined = joined + sep + strs[i];
        }
    }

    return joined;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next() you probably want `nextLine()`

Comment: You might also want to use `StringBuilder` for string concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in your `main` method

```
 String trans = translate(inp.next());
```

Into

```
 String trans = translate(inp.nextLine());
```